# tikz Sudoko-type grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, sudoku

I borrowed code for a Sudoku grid example from Roberto Bonvallet at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sudoku/ and modified it to make a different grid. In the first column of my 5 by 5 grid, I'm trying to have, from top to bottom, the numbers 3,2,1,0, then a blank. However, there are two blanks, then a 3,1, and another blank. I do not understand what is going wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
 \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
 %%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}
\newcommand\setrow[9]{
\setcounter{col}{1}
 \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5} {
 \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
 \edef\y{5.5 - \value{row}}
 \node[anchor=center] at (\x, \y) {\n};
 \stepcounter{col}
 }
 \stepcounter{row}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

\begin{scope}
\draw (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
\draw[very thin] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
\draw[thick,->] (1,1) -- (5,1);
\draw[thick,->] (1,1) -- (1,5);
\draw[thick](1,4) --(4,4);
\draw[thick](4,1) --(4,4);
\setcounter{row}{3}
\setrow {3}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow {2}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow {1}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow {0}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow { }{0}{1}{2}{3}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

### The problems:

- You had a missing closing brace in the definition of `\setrow` (after `\stepcounter{row}`).
- You had 9 arguments declared for `\setrow` (from the original code) and you were invoking `\setrow` with five arguments. Since you only need 5 for your definition I changed to `\newcommand\setrow[5]{...}`; otherwise, with 9 arguments you will have to use `\setrow{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}`.
- You need to change the settings in `\setrow` to have a proper positioning of the numbers. Change `\edef\y{5.5 - \value{row}}` to `\edef\y{7.5 - \value{row}}`

### The ammended code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
 \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
 %%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}

\newcommand\setrow[5]{
  \setcounter{col}{1}
  \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5} {
    \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
    \edef\y{7.5 - \value{row}}
    \node[anchor=center] at (\x, \y) {\n};
    \stepcounter{col}
  }
  \stepcounter{row}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

\begin{scope}
\draw (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
\draw[very thin] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
\draw[thick,->] (1,1) -- (5,1);
\draw[thick,->] (1,1) -- (1,5);
\draw[thick](1,4) --(4,4);
\draw[thick](4,1) --(4,4);
\setcounter{row}{3}
\setrow{3}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow {2}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow {1}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow {0}{}{ }{}{ }
\setrow { }{0}{1}{2}{3}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here another approach to your problem. It works as long as you got sequences of numbers that can be calculated out of your grid's coordinates. In the following code a `foreach` loop is used with the `evaluate` function to place the `nodes` at the corresponding coordinate with an offset.

If you want to use values as text in the `nodes` that cannot be calculated out of the coordinates using a `foreach` loop, you can use a `foreach` looping over two values (e.g. `\foreach \x\y in {1/9,2/4,3/7} ...`).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,-1) grid (4,4);
    \draw [<->, very thick] (0,4) |- (4,0);
    \draw [very thick] (0,3) -| (3,0);
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using \x+.5] in {0,...,3} {
        \node at (\y,-.5) {\x};
        \node at (-.5,\y) {\x};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]